# how can i set custom color of data in amCharts

Tags: amcharts

I have a stanadart data form form my graphics.

```
var data = [
  {"product": "Laptop",   "sellOfMonth": 250},
  {"product": "Phone",    "sellOfMonth": 1250},
  {"product": "Comupter", "sellOfMonth": 20}
];
```

Fro thi data my data values are sellOfMonth property. And I have a new array for style of this data like this:

```
var styles = [{"name":"sellOfMonth", "color": "#123"}];
```

This style will be color of column chart.

If my data is stacked:

```
var data = [
  {"product": "Laptop",   "sellOfMonth": 250, "sellOfYear": 2500},
  {"product": "Phone",    "sellOfMonth": 1250, "sellOfYear": 1500},
  {"product": "Comupter", "sellOfMonth": 20,, "sellOfYear": 200}
];
```

and style array is:

```
var styles = [
       {"name":"sellOfMonth", "color": "#123"},
       {"name":"sellOfYear", "color": "#dfc"}
];
```

So I can create an amchart and set dataProvider as my `data` array.

But I could not set the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how your styles are set up, you can easily use that to create your `graphs` array and set each graph's [`fillColors`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#fillColors) property to the desired color.

```
var graphs = styles.map(function(style) {
  return {
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": style.name,
    "fillColors": style.color,
    "lineColor": style.color,
    "fillAlphas": .8
  };
});
```

From there you can assign your graphs array to makeChart or the object's `graphs` array if you're using the library's class-based methods.

Demo below:

```js
var styles = [
       {"name":"sellOfMonth", "color": "#123"},
       {"name":"sellOfYear", "color": "#dfc"}
];
var graphs = styles.map(function(style) {
  return {
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": style.name,
    "fillColors": style.color,
    "lineColor": style.color,
    "fillAlphas": .8
  };
});
var data = [
  {"product": "Laptop",   "sellOfMonth": 250, "sellOfYear": 2500},
  {"product": "Phone",    "sellOfMonth": 1250, "sellOfYear": 1500},
  {"product": "Comupter", "sellOfMonth": 20, "sellOfYear": 200}
];

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "regular"
  }],
  "dataProvider": data,
  "graphs": graphs,
  "categoryField": "product"
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for useful help. How can I set the legend? Legend text will be "[title]:[value]"

Comment: Set the [`title`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#title) property in the graph object when you create them. That property is tied to the `[[title]]` shortcode in the legend.